# 'TypeError: _Options__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_17__.options.licenses[i] is undefined' error on a ReactJS project using amcharts4?

Tags: reactjs, amcharts, amcharts4

I have a ReactJS project that uses amcharts4. On my clients machine, it works completely fine. However, on mine, I cannot get it to run. Every time I try I get this error:

```
TypeError: _Options__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_17__.options.licenses[i] is undefined
./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/Container.js/Container.prototype.hasLicense
node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/Container.js:2123
```

It seems to be occuring after I run this:

```
let graph = am4core.create(id, am4charts.XYChart);
```

I have all the amcharts env vars setup properly, including valid API keys. I've tried deleting node modules and reinstalling. I've tried clearing my NPM cache and checking/confirming that my API key is indeed correct.